# C++ vector size and iterator result different size

Tags: c++

I recently discovered a problem, but don't know if it is a bug.

Code

```
void LeakFolding::ComputeDAG() {
  SCCList<LeakInfo> scc_list{allocator_};
  Tarjan(leak_graph_, scc_list);

  Allocator<SCCInfo> scc_allocator = allocator_;

  for (auto& scc_nodes : scc_list) {
    Allocator<SCCInfo>::unique_ptr leak_scc;
    leak_scc = scc_allocator.make_unique(scc_allocator);

    for (auto& node : scc_nodes) {
      node->ptr->scc = leak_scc.get();
      leak_scc->count++;
      leak_scc->size += node->ptr->range.size();
    }
    leak_scc_.emplace_back(std::move(leak_scc));
    MEM_ALOGI("debug leak_scc_ emplace_back after size: %d reference_in size: %d", (int)leak_scc_.size(), (int)leak_scc_.back()->node.references_in.size());
  }

  MEM_ALOGI("leak_scc_ size: %d", (int)leak_scc_.size());
  for (auto& it : leak_scc_){
        MEM_ALOGI("leak_scc_ node references_in_ size: %d.....", (int)it->node.references_in.size());
  }

  .....
}
```

LOG

```
04-29 18:17:53.208  3038  3037 I libmemunreachable: collecting thread info for process 3037...
04-29 18:17:53.211  3038  3037 I libmemunreachable: collection thread done
04-29 18:17:53.212  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: searching process 3037 for allocations
04-29 18:17:53.213  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: searching done
04-29 18:17:53.213  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: sweeping process 3037 for unreachable memory
04-29 18:17:53.218  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: sweeping done
04-29 18:17:53.218  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: folding related leaks
04-29 18:17:53.218  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: debug leak_scc_ emplace_back after size: 1 reference_in size: 0
04-29 18:17:53.218  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: debug leak_scc_ emplace_back after size: 2 reference_in size: 0
04-29 18:17:53.218  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: debug leak_scc_ emplace_back after size: 3 reference_in size: 0
04-29 18:17:53.218  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: debug leak_scc_ emplace_back after size: 4 reference_in size: 0
04-29 18:17:53.218  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: leak_scc_ size: 4
04-29 18:17:53.218  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: leak_scc_ node references_in_ size: 0.....
04-29 18:17:53.219  3039  3039 I chatty  : uid=0(root) libmemunreachab identical 2 lines
04-29 18:17:53.219  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: leak_scc_ node references_in_ size: 0.....
04-29 18:17:53.219  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: debug node edge size 4 reference_in(0)  size 0
04-29 18:17:53.219  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: debug leak_scc_ during after leak_scc_ size 4 reference_in(0)  size 1
04-29 18:17:53.219  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: debug node edge size 4 reference_in(0)  size 1
04-29 18:17:53.219  3039  3039 I libmemunreachable: debug leak_scc_ during after leak_scc_ size 4 reference_in(0)  size 1
...
```

leak_scc_.size() is 4, but use iterator is 2? 
Why is the iterator only 2 times?
i don't know much about C ++, can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is the use of iterators that produces 2 in output? Create a [mcve]

Comment: Looks like your logging library has functionality to accumulate duplicate logs: `I chatty  : uid=0(root) libmemunreachab identical 2 lines` so it looks like it works as it supposed to, you just misread logs.